# If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, then find the number of ordered triplets $(a,b,c)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $$f(x)=a\lvert\sin x|+b \cdot e^{-|x|}+c \cdot |x|^{2015}$$

$0 \leq a,b,c \leq 10$, $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, then find the number of ordered triplets $(a,b,c)$

$(A)$ $0$

$(B)$ $10$

$(C)$ $100$

$(D)$ $1000$

Could someone help me with this problem? I have found that $f(x)=a\lvert\sin x|+b \cdot e^{-|x|}+c \cdot |x|^{2015}$ is differentiable at $x=0$ but I have no idea how to find ordered pairs?

Comment: If $f(x)$ where differentiable, then any choice for $a,b,c$ will work. You would have 11 choices for each, and so $1331$ would be the answer. Unless you meant that the product $abc$ is an integer, in which case there would be infinite. Are you sure you showed it is always differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0^+}\left(a\frac{\sin h}{h}+b\frac{e^{-h}-1}{h}+ch^{2014}\right)
$$
(it is not restrictive to assume $0<h<\pi/2$, so $\lvert\sin h\rvert=\sin h$).

Note that the first summand has limit $a$, the second summand has limit $-b$ and the third summand has limit $0$; so the limit is $a-b$.

Now try with the limit for $h\to0^-$. The two limits should be equal. Can you finish? Be careful with the signs.